# List hard links of a file C

Tags: c, unix, hardlink

I need to list all hard links of a given file in "pure" C, so without help of bash commands.

I googled for hours but couldn't find anything useful.
My current idea is to get inode number then loop through directory to find files with same inode.

In bash something like

```
 sudo find / -inum 199053
```

Any better suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: This seems UNIX-specific, so I added a tag for you.

Comment: At the very least, you can do a short-circuit optimization by using `stat` to find out the number of hard links *n* and abort the file system traversal after you have found *n* links (or entirely avoid in case of *n* = 1).  But apart from this, I don't know of a more efficient solution.

Comment: You'll want to start the `find` from the filesystem's mount point (which may or may not be `/`), and use the `-xdev` option to stay within that filesystem (since hard links can't cross filesystem boundaries). I don't think there's a better way to do it. Why do you need to do it in "pure C"? The `find` command is likely to be at least as efficient as whatever you can write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the inode number of a single file, invoke the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function and reference the st_ino value of the returned struct.

```
int result;
struct stat s;
result = stat("filename.txt", &s);
if ((result == 0) && (s.st_ino == 199053))
{
   // match
}
```

You could build a solution with the stat function using [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), and [closedir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) to recursively scan a directory hierarchy to look for matching inode values.

You could also use [scandir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir) to scan an entire directory:

```
int filter(const struct dirent* entry)
{
    return (entry->d_ino == 199053) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{ 
    struct dirent **namelist = NULL;
    scandir("/home/selbie", &namelist, filter, NULL);
    free(namelist);
    return 0;
}
```